# “while(*s++ = *t++)” and malloc

Tags: c, string, copy, malloc

I found following code piece to be confusing when I want to do a manual string copy.

```
int strincmp(char *s1) {
    int l1 = strlen(s1)+1;
    char *s1_copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * l1);
    while(*s1_copy++=*s1++);
    printf("s1_copy = %s , s1 = %s \n",s1_copy,s1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is confusing since I expect it to output a copied string. but it is as follows:

```
s1_copy =  , s1 =
```

When I replace the "while(*s1_copy++=*s1++);" statement with the following naive way(treat s1_copy and s1 as arrays instead of ptrs)

```
int i=0;
while( s1[i] != '\0'){
    s1_copy[i] = s1[i];
    i++;
}   
s1_copy[i] = '\0';
```

The output is what I expected.

```
s1_copy = TenaLynetta , s1 = TenaLynetta
```

This is confusing for me, why the first way does not work. And hopefully this is a meaningful question.

Comment: weird name for a copy command?

Comment: Did you add the printf yourself ? It's obviously not going to do anything useful, because the pointers have been incremented beyond the ends of their respective strings. Move the printf out of the function or keep copies of the original pointers.

Comment: @PaulR, in which case shouldn't the original string also not be printed? Had it been moved to its end, we would have seen no outputs from both prints.

Comment: @envy_intelligence: the pointers will actually have been (post-)incremented to one character beyond the terminating `\0` of each string, so they are both pointing at undefined locations - what then gets printed can be literally anything, since it's Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thank you guys. It is a naive misunderstanding. The problem is I moved the pointers and when I want to printf the pointer is no longer at the beginning place.

Comment: Shortcut: rather than `while(*s1_copy++=*s1++);`, use `memcpy(s1_copy, s1, ll);`

Answer (score 3):

You make your pointer point to first location of the allocated memory

```
s1_copy
  |
-----------------------------------
| h   | e   |  l  | l   | o | \0  |
-----------------------------------
```

In the while loop you keep incrementing the pointer so at the end of the while loop the pointer is actually pointing to the end of the string and not to the beginining of the string.

```
                                   s1_copy
                                      |
-------------------------------------------
| h   | e   |  l  | l   | o | \0  | ----- |
-------------------------------------------
```

`%s` prints out the string until the `\0` character is encountered. Since the pointer is pointing to some location in memory which is not under your control and you try to print the string from there then it leads to undefined behavior.

The original string is also modified the same way but because of undefined behavior you are seeing the proper/improper output.

When there is undefined behavior you never know what actually happens

Comment: disagree about "there is nothing to be printed".  `s1_copy`, like `s1`, is also pass its space.  `printf("s1_copy = %s\n",s1_copy);` is also UB.

Comment: @chux My bad!! I made it sound like it is defined behavior.. I wanted say that both causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both the pointers s1_copy and s1 increments and reaches the end of the string (NULL character '\0').

or you can use it like this way to keep a pointer to the start of string and print it at the end.( Two extra pointers are required so not much recommended )

```
int strincmp(char *s1) {
    int l1 = strlen(s1)+1;
    char *s1_dup = s1;
    char *s1_copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * l1);
    char *s1_copy_dup = s1_copy;
    while(*s1_copy++=*s1++);
    s1_copy = s1_copy_dup;
    s1 = s1_dup;
    printf("s1_copy = %s , s1 = %s \n",s1_copy,s1);
    return 0;
}
```